# Finding the best 1-rank approximation

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

I am trying to solve a 5x5 matrix to find first SVD and then 1-rank approximation but I have a problem in finding the eigenvaluse of it [image: This is the matrix]

Comment: Although your sentence does not make much sense imho I recommend to do a LU decomposition via Gaussian Elimination of your matrix, and afterwards the eigenvalues are the values on the diagonal of U. This needs only some simple computations. 
Afterwards you can verify your answer with e.g. http://www.wolframalpha.com

Comment: For the SVD and the best 1-rank approximation, you need the eigenvalues of $A^TA,$ but not the eigenvalues of $A.$

Comment: The martrix here is A^T A not A itself

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by LU decomposition ?